# About JAX-RPC specification and Serialization in Java

Tags: java, axis

A have created a web service using eclipse plugin present in it (generate java bean skeleton). The classes thus created are using java.lang.Class and java.lang.Object. But when I use those classes eclipse shows that project does not comply with JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. And after that it said   **Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer**

Can any one tell me what I can use for this.

Here is one of the class generated.

```
public class Address  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private java.lang.String type;

    private java.lang.String value;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(
        java.lang.String type, java.lang.String value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the type value for this Address.
     */
    public java.lang.String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the type value for this Address.
     */
    public void setType(java.lang.String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value value for this Address.
     * 
     * @return value
     */
    public java.lang.String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value value for this Address.
     * 
     * @param value
     */
    public void setValue(java.lang.String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;
    public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Address)) return false;
        Address other = (Address) obj;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (__equalsCalc != null) {
            return (__equalsCalc == obj);
        }
        __equalsCalc = obj;
        boolean _equals;
        _equals = true && 
            ((this.type==null && other.getType()==null) || 
             (this.type!=null &&
              this.type.equals(other.getType()))) &&
            ((this.value==null && other.getValue()==null) || 
             (this.value!=null &&
              this.value.equals(other.getValue())));
        __equalsCalc = null;
        return _equals;
    }

    private boolean __hashCodeCalc = false;
    public synchronized int hashCode() {
        if (__hashCodeCalc) {
            return 0;
        }
        __hashCodeCalc = true;
        int _hashCode = 1;
        if (getType() != null) {
            _hashCode += getType().hashCode();
        }
        if (getValue() != null) {
            _hashCode += getValue().hashCode();
        }
        __hashCodeCalc = false;
        return _hashCode;
    }

    // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(Address.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://ws.spherecom.com/", "Address"));
        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = 
                                        new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("type");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://ws.spherecom.com/", "type"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("value");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://ws.spherecom.com/", "value"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return new org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return new org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for using JAX-RPC/Axis? JAX-WS is rather more modern and uses JAXB for this sort of thing (i.e., is somewhat less troublesome).